# Does this limit separation work?

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider the following limit:

$$L=\lim_{x\to a}\left(\frac{f(x)g(x)}{p(x)q(x)}\right)~,~a\in\Bbb{R}$$

I know that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)}{p(x)}$ and the limit $L$ both exist finitely. Now, I was wondering whether we could separate the limits in $L$ like this using the info we have till now?

$$L=\left(\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{p(x)}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)}{q(x)}\right)$$

**Note:** At $x=a$, the body of the limit $L$ is undefined (**not** in the form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$).

Actually, I wanted to know this to prove another result that uses the following idea. I was trying at that other problem using proof by contradiction and I need to know whether this method of separation works to conclude my proof of that problem. I don't want to post that other problem, so I'm posting this general question.

Comment: You can separate limits like that provided that you know that all the limits in the separated version exist and are finite.

Comment: @TravisJ, the thing is, I wanted to employ this in a proof by contradiction where I'll later prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)}{q(x)}$ doesn't exist finitely and hence conclude my proof. So, you see, we can't use that.

Comment: If the limit of $f(x)/p(x)$ is $0$, strange things can happen.

Comment: If the body of the limit is undefined in a diverging manner (Such as $\frac\infty{c}$ or $\frac c0$, the equality $L=\ldots$ must fail because you just said that the RHS is undefined. So what is it exactly that you know of $\frac{f(x)g(x)}{p(x)q(x)}$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Assume that the limit of $f(x)/p(x)$ is $1$ for simplicity's sake. That assumption would work for me since the problem I'm dealing with has that.

Comment: @AlexR, I'm not getting what you mean! $L$ **isn't** another limit. I denoted the given limit by $L$ to better present the problem.

Comment: @learner:   Then the limit separation of your post works.

Comment: @learner I'm asking you to specify what "The body of the limit at $x=a$ is undefined" means precisely, because that seems to be a source of the problem.

Comment: @AlexR, that simply means $\dfrac{f(a)g(a)}{p(a)q(a)}$ is undefined. Sorry for any ambiguity that my wording may have created.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, that is exactly what I wanted to hear! Thanks! :D

Comment: @learner Ah okay then there's no problem. It's an application of $\lim \frac fg = \frac{\lim f}{\lim g}$ if $|\lim f| < \infty$ and $0\ne |\lim g| <\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the limits
$$L_a = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{p(x)}$$
and
$$L = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)g(x)}{p(x)q(x)}$$
exist and are finite. Additionally $L_a = 1 \ne 0$ so we know that
$$L_b = \frac L{L_a} = \frac{\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{p(x)q(x)}}{\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{p(x)}} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{\frac{f(x)g(x)}{p(x)q(x)}}{\frac{f(x)}{p(x)}} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{g(x)}{q(x)}$$
exists and is finite. This allows us to separate the limits as you want to.